# How to use VBA to delete multiple xls files

Tags: vba, move, archive, delete-file

Using VBA Access how do I delete multple xls files ? There are 3 reports that are generated through a process that are being saved to my documents folder. In the same sense how would I move all 3 of these files to another folder if I didn't want to delete them but archive them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim fso as New FileSystemObject

fso.DeleteFile "C:\MyDocs\*.xls"
```

OR

```
fso.MoveFile "C:\MyDocs\*.xls" "C:\Archive\"
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete a file:

```
Kill "Path\to\file.xls"
```

To move a file:

```
Name "Path\to\file.xls" As "New\Path\to\file.xls"
```